# webBrowser control won't redirect although IE 9 Mango does

Tags: windows-phone-7

I have a a link that redirects to another. The destination link is a link to a video.

The problem is that i can't get the destination link because the `WebBrowser` doesn't redirect to it. When i use IE9 with my initial link, it redirects me to the desired link, but when i use a `WebBrowser` control, using the same initial link, it doesn't do nothing. How can i enable this?

(i.e. the `WebBrowser` has the isScriptEnabled true) .

The webservice that i use is user-agent sensitive(it gives video for diferent devices) but it isn't mean for non-browser usage, so this is probably the issue.

Because `HttpWebRequest` and `WebClient` don't render pages (so i can't redirect to the page i want) i need to use a `webBrowser`. Parsing the response for that request isn't a solution(no data usable in the response so that i can get the redirect link)

Comment: does your webbrowser control have scripting enabled?

Comment: quote : "(i.e. the WebBrowser has the isScriptEnabled true)"

Comment: woops, skimmed your question. so does redirect occur via a script or a meta redirect? what's the output of the page where the stall occurs.

Comment: it should redirect via meta but it doesn't.

Comment: <meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0; url=http://dottalent.staging.cloud.g-box.tv/video/2179/play?width=176&height=144\">

Comment: can you paste the js code your redirect is using? I have checked for a string in the output myself at one point because it was a page without any redirect but needed to go somewhere else afterwards. maybe you could do that.

Comment: so there must be something wrong in the way meta redirect works on windows phone. try to make your own page with a meta redirect to see if it works.

Comment: the thing is that in the IE9 browser on the phone it works just fine! weird..

Comment: you'll have to scan for meta redirect as it doesn't seem to be implemented on the control

Comment: Try using this URL as your initial target: http://chriskoenig.net/test.htm

I built a very simple app that just navigates a web browser control to this page and it seemed to redirect just fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have seen the web browser control fail to redirect on a few occasions. What I did was just look for the meta tag myself, and then redirect to the page manually. It is by no means pretty, but it works

Comment: Thanks for the feedback on your experience! That's what i'm gonna do myself!

Answer (score 0):

Recently encountered with the same issue while implementing facebook registration logic via embedded webcontrol. My solution was to redirect to the same page again, the code

```
void browser_LoadCompleted(object sender, System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    // TODO FIX HACK
    // sometimes web browser does not redirect to callback url during facebook authentication
    // so we refresh the page
    if (e.Uri.ToString().StartsWith(@"https://www.facebook.com/dialog/permissions.request") &&
        browser.SaveToString().Contains("window.location.href=\"http:\\/\\/www.facebook.com\\/connect\\/login_success.html"))
    {
        browser.Navigate(e.Uri);

    }
}
```